# scanForPeripheralsWithServices:return result twice on the same peripheral

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I use the below code

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:serviceUUIDArray 
         options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] 
         forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey]]
```

to scan a perpheral device, then the result return twice on the same peripheral. How to return one? Thanks.

Comment: Filter by UUID... Drop it if it doen't have one yet (still not given)

Comment: UUID is available on the peripheral only if it had been connected before. New peripherals don't have UUIDs. Filtering the ones with `nil` UUID out would effectively disable finding new peripherals.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the peripheral's name is updated. In this case you get the callback once more.

This thread contains a detailed explanation: http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2013/Apr/msg00099.html

Credits go to Etan Kissling:

> The device name is cached by iOS according to a priority list:
>
> 1. Name read from Device name characteristic after a connect
> 2. Name from advertising packet
> 3. null
>
> Note that the name from the advertising packet should be a prefix of
>   the final name in the Device name characteristic.
>
> Maybe the physical device already had the name cached, and does not
>   send the second update, as it already retrieved the name.
>
> Your app should be able to deal with duplicates even when you don't
>   request them.

To deal with duplicates, you can check the already received ones with the `isEqualTo:` method on the peripheral or use an `NSSet` for storing them.

Comment: @Etan Are you kidding? I even gave you reps for it.

Comment: @Etan , you're the best! (To clarify my comment above.)